# Installing a Ruby version with rvm froze my computer--can I test to see if it installed correctly?

Tags: ruby, 64-bit, rvm

I recently refreshed my Linux installation with Mint 9 (based on Ubuntu 10.04) 64-bit, no Ruby packages at all, and started with a clean install of rvm.

But when I ran `rvm install 1.9.2`, after half an hour or so of some heavy CPU usage the computer froze altogether. I powered down and restarted it, and rvm tells me that ruby-1.9.2-p0 is installed.

Same story when I ran `rvm install 1.8.7' just now.

Should I be surprised? **More importantly, how can I know if the Ruby versions installed are really going to work correctly--is there a test I can run?**

Comment: I don't think anything *should* freeze your computer.

Comment: Do you have a system ruby installe?  I might be wrong here, but I've always thought you actually need to have a system version of ruby in order for rvm to be able to compile the versions that it tries to install

Comment: A system that freezes when you compile software sounds like a job for superuser.com.

Comment: I have this bug too with my Ubuntu 10.10 amd64 on my HP Elitebook 8440p (which is fast enough), sometime it causes CPU overheat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How fast is your computer?  This makes all the difference here.  On a slow computer, especially if it doesn't have much RAM, compiling larger projects can be painful.  I remember my netbook really struggled compiling Ruby.  It took something like half an hour.  And that's with upgraded RAM, if I had 512MB or something, it would have taken much longer.

Edit: I can only guess what you mean by "freeze," but I'm guessing you ran out of RAM and were thrashing SWAP.  This is recoverable, if you're patient, but it would be easier to reboot if that happens.

Comment: This laptop is not a slouch--a Core 2 Duo with 3GB RAM. It's typical for a complex compile to take a few minutes with a lot of CPU, but interrupts and such work okay so the computer is still usable. So this situation seems... extreme.

Comment: Strange, I half expected you to say it was a netbook or some antiquated machine.  All I can say now is "it shouldn't be doing that."